# Why do I get a LEFT OUTER JOIN error msg when i'm not even using a left join?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

**LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.**

Why do I get the above BQ error msg when running the below query? I'm not using any left outer join. Thanks!

````
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT
        *
      , (select sum(transaction_amount) from `analytics-111.tmp.coll` where transaction_date_est <= mq.transaction_date_est) RunningTotal      
   FROM `analytics-111.tmp.coll` mq) mq2
WHERE mq2.RunningTotal < 1000 ```
````

Comment: The select sum subquery is probably converted to a left join (internally).

Comment: Never met bq, my guess is try aliases for every table.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is just another way of expressing a `left join`.  The optimizer recognizes the issue after rewriting the query -- and the error message doesn't know if the original code is a `LEFT JOIN` or correlated subquery.  The error message could be fixed.

Happily, you can calculate this using a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT mq.*,
       SUM(mq.transaction_amount) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_amount) as RunningTotal      
FROM `analytics-111.tmp.coll` mq
QUALIFY mq.RunningTotal < 1000;
```

Note that this uses the new `QUALIFY` clause which allows you to filter on window functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use window functions due to a few in-house limitations - this is why I'm trying an alternative method. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user15067132 . . . That does not make sense to me.  BigQuery supports window functions.  What could you be doing in-house that would prevent the use of supported, standard functionality?